# SQL query calculating 2 separate columns of data based on date range group by size and type

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 separate sql queries (shown below) that work well but I need to show the data in one table as begInv, acqQty, isize, type. 
How do I show the 2 columns together with separate date ranges in the same table for the given size and type?

```
SELECT 
      Sum(i.Qty) as begInv
      ,i.Size
      ,i.Type     
  FROM InvDetails i
  join Acquisition a
  on i.SerialNo = a.SerialNo
  where a.DtAcquired < '1/25/2014' 
  group by i.Size, i.Type

SELECT 
      Sum(i.Qty) as acqqty
      ,i.Size
      ,i.Type     
  FROM InvDetails i
  join Acquisition a
  on i.SerialNo = a.SerialNo
  where a.DtAcquired between '1/25/2014' and '3/15/2014'
  group by i.Size, i.Type
```

The data would look like that when combined:
begInv  acqqty  Size    Type
0   5   Pint    ice cream
0   6   16 oz   soda
1   8   gallon  soda
3   46  5 oz.   soda
0   15  50 ML   soda
0   11  5 ML    soda
0   9   7 Ounce cream
1   12  Pint    cream
1   4   75 ML   milk
1   6   Pint    milk

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what the result set would look like? I'm having a huge problem visualizing what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT Sum(case when a.DtAcquired < '2014-01-25'
                then i.Qty
                else 0
           end) as begqty,
       Sum(case when a.DtAcquired between '2014-01-25' and '2014-03-15'
                then i.Qty
                else 0
           end) as acqqty,
       i.Size, i.Type     
FROM InvDetails i join
     Acquisition a
     on i.SerialNo = a.SerialNo
group by i.Size, i.Type;
```

Note that I changed the date formats to use ANSI standard format; this is a bit safer than the form you used (which can be ambiguous as to whether it is mmddyyyy or ddmmyyyy).

Comment: thank you that is exactly what I was looking for! I had the case statements but had the sum inside of it instead of around it. :)